# Fundamental Group of a Connected Graph with (at least) Two Cycles

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

If $G$ is a connected graph with least two cycles, it is true that for a base point vertex $v$,  $\pi_1(G,v) \cong \mathbb{Z}^r$ for $r \geq 2$?

I think I have some intuition as to why this is the case, but I'm having trouble formalizing it. Suppose we're in the case where $G$ has two cycles. If one took a maximal spanning tree $T$ of $G$ and contracted it to $V$, one would be left with two circles which meet at $v$, giving rise to two non-trivial loops, and each contributing a generator (which won't have relations between them) to $\pi_1(G)$.

Will the converse hold as well? If $\pi_1(G) \cong \mathbb{Z}^r$, must $G$ have $r$ cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the fundamental group of a connected graph with $r$ independent cycles
($r$ edges not in a spanning tree) is the *free group* on $r$ generators
and is not Abelian for $r\ge2$. Its Abelianisation (quotient by its commutator subgroup) is $\Bbb Z^r$, so is determined up to isomorphism by $r$.

The free group consists of words in the letters $a_1,\ldots,a_r,a_1^{-1},\ldots,a_r^{-1}$ with the obvious relations $a_ja_j^{-1}=a_j^{-1}a_j=$ the identity. When $r\ge2$, $a_1a_2\ne a_2a_1$.

Comment: I see, thanks! So for $r$ independent cycles, $rank(\pi_1(G))=r$?

Comment: @lkr Yes, that's right!

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. That goes both ways right? If I knew $rank(\pi_1(G))=r$, then the fundamental group has at least $r$ generators, so there would be $r$ circles meeting at a base point $v$, so $G$ would have $r$ cycles? Thanks!

Comment: @lkr yes again. A finite connected graph is homotopy equivalent to a bouquet of $r$ circles (just collapse spanning tree to a point).